# getting status from a servlet

Tags: servlets

How can we determine the status of a Job a servlet is doing.
If a sservlet creates a Job Object and call its do() method which takes 2 minutes to complete and we want to show the users how much task it has completed so far on the front-end.

Comment: Depends on how `Job` is implemented.

Comment: lets say this Job is having an instance variable "processCounter" which it keeps incrementing and i want to show this to user

Comment: You can just poll the server and update the status in the frontend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to

- put the job in a session attribute, for example, or in some other shared map where you can find it in a subsequent request
- start a new thread which invokes the job's long-running method
- make sure every access to the job's status is properly synchronized
- poll the server from your HTML page (by refreshing the page or submitting AJAX requests

Each polling request will just get the job from the session (or the shared map) and get its status.